# C program to count words in a given string/sentence?

Tags: c, arrays, count, character, words

I want to count the words in a given string by counting the spaces between them. Here's the code that i've tried.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
 int t,i,b=1;
 char a[100];
 printf("Enter a sentence: ");
 gets(a);
 t=strlen(a);
 for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
      if(a[i]=' ')
      {
           b++;
      }
 }
 printf("The number of words in the above sentence are %d",b);
 getch();
}
```

But i am unable to get the output. I keep getting wrong number of words.

Thanks. :D

Comment: `if(a[i]=' ')` --> `if(a[i]==' ')`

Comment: please use `fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);` because `gets()` by itself could cause problems.

Comment: Can't i use scanf? i was actually hoping for scanf, but i saw somewhere that as a beginner i should use gets for inputting user data.

Comment: By the way, fgets didn't work either. Do u think my algorithm is wrong somewhere?

Comment: `scanf()` would stop when it finds a whitespace. And whoever tells you to use `gets()` you shouldn't listen to them any further, it's a deprecated function, `fgets()` is much better obviously. Using `scanf()` or `fgets()` is not a matter of how skilled you are, but of what you need to do.

Comment: @downvoters(whoever they maybe, I am not addressing any particular person, I am just saying in general) .My account has been banned from asking questions and the stackoverflow has asked me to review my questions. I don't see how this question is wrong by any means. So if there is any improvement, please suggest so, or else please consider upvoting this question, so I get back my ability to ask questions on this site. I like stackoverflow and would like to be part of this community, so I want your help either in terms of suggestions for re-formatting the question or in form of upvotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` for comparison

```
if(a[i]=' ')
```

you need `==`

```
if(a[i] == ' ')
```

some people use this

```
if (' ' == a[i])
```

to prevent this kind of mistake.

Comment: Man, this is embarrassing. So many silly mistakes in a single day. Thanks a lot, i've been searching for this for about 30 minutes now. :D

Comment: I'd sooner turn up compile warnings than use "Yoda conditions". With `-Wall -Wextra`, gcc gave me `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]`.